# Impala group by output based on select statement

Tags: group-by, impala

I have two Impala tables :
a) one with data that has directory paths as string and number of files in it,e.g.

```
::table1::
path  ,  file_count
/folder1/a/b/c , 6
/folder1/a/b/c/d , 2
/folder2/x/y/z/r , 3
/folder2/x/y/z/y , 4
/folder3/dont/care/a, 3
/folder3/dont/care/a/b, 7
```

b) second table has specific folders as string

```
::table2::
folders
/folder1/a
/folder2/x/y/z
```

I would like to write a single Impala query to give this output

```
path_out, file_count_aggregate
/folder1/a, 8
/folder2/x/y/z, 7
```

where its aggregating file_counts at the level of directories specified in my second table

I am not sure how to do this as it means i have to filter table 1 with entries from table 2 and aggregate based on the start strings of table 2

I tried

```
    select path, sum(file_count) from table1 where path rlike (select distinct folders from table2) group by 1
```

this just gives the filtered rows in table1

```
path  ,  file_count
/folder1/a/b/c , 6
/folder1/a/b/c/d , 2
/folder2/x/y/z/r , 3
/folder2/x/y/z/y , 4
```

but i need the aggregate now based on the paths in table2.  somehow i need to group by only on the exact paths specified in table2.
this is just a simple example, but i will potentially have 50k+ folders in table2 and millions of lines in table1